# How to check if an activity class is in the back stack and manage it accordingly in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I want to check if an object with a specific class is in the back stack. If so, I will use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, If not, I want to pop to root and push the Class.

Suppose that I have A,C,D in the stack and I want to add B.
As B does not exist in the stack (here), I want the stack to become A,B (clearing C,D and pushing B).

If I had A,B,C,D in the stack, it would have popped C,D without pushing B.

Is there a way to do this without clearing everything in stack and pushing Class A with Intent parameter of "GoToClass" and pushing the class "GoToClass" after loading -root- A?

From Android documentation:

> **public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**
>
> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Answer (score 1):

When the activity is destroyed or Removed from the back stack the final method that will be called is on `onDestroy()`. Now in your `onDestroy()` method save a variable and save this in your  **Shared preferences** or create a class variable and check the value in that variable not equals to null. If the variable has some value then definitely `onDestroy()` Method was called and your activity is no longer in back stack.